# The dimension of a Polyhedron using its vertices

Tags: polyhedra

We are giving a Polyhedron:

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

The vertices or the extreme points of P is: (1,1,-3), (1,-3,1), (-3,-1,1)

We know from Linear Algebra that:
Since the points are linearly independent; is the Dim(p)=3 ?
 - But is there no other linearly independent points in P?

In my book: Undergraduate Convexity
It follows that if a set is affinely independent with m points (vectors) is the dim(P) = m-1
So by go a dimension up is the vertices of P affinely independent: (1,1,-3,1), (1,-3,1,1), (1,-3,1,1), (-3,-1,1,1)
But we do need a 4th point that is affinely independent with these vectors, right?
But isn't there infinitely many points in R^4 for P that is affinely independent?: 
Ex. the point (-1,-3,-1,1) which is in P, and is affinely independent with the 3 vertices.

So the dim(P) = m-1 1 = 4 -1 = 3 as the number of linearly independent points in P

Whats is the best way to determine the dim(P)?

Comment: P = x in R^3 st. Ax<=b

Comment: There is 4 rows in A

Answer (score 0):

You have three points, not collinear. Their convex hull is a triangle,
in some plane. So it has dimension $2$.

In general with points $P_1,\ldots,P_n$, the dimension of their
convex hull is the dimension of the vector space spanned by
$\vec{P_1P_2},\vec{P_1P_3},\ldots,\vec{P_1P_n}$.